# SQL Server 1 million records: best way to get fastest last record of table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 1 million records: best way to get fastest last record of table?

**Example:** I have a table A with 1 million records. What is the way to get fastest last records?

**I know:** `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM A ORDER BY ID DESC`

But I think It's not good way for me.

Comment: The query in your question will perform very well if you have a clustered index (including primary key) on `ID`. That is the best way.

Comment: `But I think It's not good way for me.` <= Why do you "think" that? Did you try it? Did you measure the response time? Did you profile it with Sql Profiler?

Comment: Define "last record". What indexes do you have on the table?

Answer (score 2):

The query in your question will perform very well if you have a clustered index (which may be the primary key index) on ID. There is no faster way to retrieve all columns from a single row of a table.

I'll add that a table is logically an unordered set of rows so `ORDER BY` is required to return a "last" or "first" row. The b-tree index on the `ORDER BY` column will locate the row efficiently.

Comment: thanks.. how does the B-tree Index works internally in the order by sorting .. any advise would be helpful

Comment: @goofyui, see [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2017) that details SQL Server b-tree architecture. To find the first (or last) row ordered by an index key, SQL Server reads the first (or last) entry of each index level from top to bottom. The number of logical reads (work done) is the number of index levels and the number of levels is smallest with a clustered index.

Comment: Dan, Thank you .. explanation is well said.. easy to follow thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 0):

you have only one way index on primary key and where values . order by has a little bit cost but it's ok if you has index on order Column

```
--ORDER BY 1 DESC means order by primary key index desc
SELECT [Columns] FROM [TABLENAME] ORDER BY 1 DESC 

--or you can use this if your first column is IDENTITY or A/A
SELECT [Columns] FROM [TABLENAME] ORDER BY [YOUR_COLUMN_WITHA/A ] DESC
```